# How to calculate the denominator of Bayes' Rule

Tags: bayes-theorem

I'm currently working through the example of applying Bayes rule to a scenario in [this chapter](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/networks-book-ch16.pdf) on page 491.

This is the information I've been given:

$$\operatorname{Pr}(B) = 0.8$$
$$\operatorname{Pr}(Y) = 0.2$$
$$\operatorname{Pr}(\text{report} = Y \mid \text{true} = Y) = 0.8$$
$$\operatorname{Pr}(\text{report} = B \mid \text{true} = B) = 0.8$$

What I want to calculate using Bayes' rule is the following

$$\operatorname{Pr}(\text{true} = Y \mid \text{report} = Y) = \frac{\operatorname{Pr}(\text{true}=Y) \cdot \operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y \mid \text{true}=Y)}{\operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y)}$$

I have managed to calculate the numerator which is:
$$\operatorname{Pr}(\text{true}=Y) \cdot \operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y \mid \text{true}=Y) = 0.2 \cdot 0.8 = 0.16$$

I have managed to calculate the first part of the denominator:

$$\operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y) = \operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y \cap \text{true}=Y) + \operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y \cap \text{true}=B)$$
$$\operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y \cap \text{true}=Y) = \operatorname{Pr}(\text{true}=Y) \cdot \operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y \mid \text{true}=y) = 0.2 \cdot 0.8 = 0.16$$

What I am confused about is how do I calculate $\operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y \mid \text{true}=B)$ for the second part of the denominator using the information I already have? The textbook states that it is $0.2$ but I'm not certain how they concluded that.

Comment: You can get proper spacing by using `\mid` instead of `|`, and proper fonts by using `\text{...}` for text that shouldn't be in italics and `\operatorname{name}` for operators like $\operatorname{Pr}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the report is either $B$ or $Y$, you have

$$\operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=Y\mid\text{true}=B)=1-\operatorname{Pr}(\text{report}=B\mid\text{true}=B)\;.$$